# Not able to make an HTTP access to SQL Server Analysis services 2008 on Windows Server 2008 via IIS 7

Tags: http, iis-7, ssas

My intention is to access the SSAS Database without Windows authentication. The user outside the domain should be able to access the cube and built PIVOT tables around it. Thus I found that we can use HTTP access for this purpose.

I followed each and every step mentioned on the following links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx

When I try to hit the URL in Mgmt Studio --> Analysis Services

http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll. I am getting the "Connection time out" and "404 error"

I went to MSDN forums for the same problem but no concrete results.

How do I test whether my SSAS 2008 is accessible with HTTP access.

Please help!!

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot to go on from your question, but if I had to guess I'd say you probably didn't switch from integrated to classic in the application pool settings which left your handler mapping disabled giving you the 404.

I would start simple on your local development machine and follow the instructions allowing anonymous access to the site. Make sure that your site uses an application pool that has access to the cube in analysis services. Additionally, you cannot use the integrated pipeline in IIS, you will hve to use classic. When you create your script mapping (under Handler Mappings) in IIS, make sure that you follow the directions carefully from the following URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

I just followed the instructions and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching on Anonymous authentication will work to grant access to the site, however I would suggest you use at least Basic HTTP authentication or even Windows Authentication. Just note, if you're using a remote SSAS instance (not on the same host), a double-hop authentication is required. For that, you will have to register SPNs and enable Kerberos authentication.

You find out how to do that by following the links referred to under 
[Microsoft - Configure HTTP Access to SSAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx)

Greetings,
Remo